# A few general questions about Service Reference and MVVM pattern

Tags: wcf, web-services, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

There is a web service.

- It provides types `Zoo` and `Animal`.
- `Zoo` has a dictionary of animal ids and names.
- `Animal` has properties: `Id`, `Name` and `(additional stuff)`.
- It has a method `GetZoo` that returns a zoo object.
- It has a method `GetAnimalStuffById` that returns an `Animal` object with `Id`, `Name` and the `(additional stuff)`.

So the idea is - `GetZoo` allows me to get a list of animal ids + names, and then `GetAnimalStuffById` fetches full animal info.

I add a "service reference" to that service in VS and want to write a MVVM app. Some things I don't fully understand and need to be brainwashed about.

1. Is it OK for autogenerated classes to be my models?
2. Not related to the example, but anyway: what "collection type" should I specify when adding service reference? Is `ObservableCollection` an overkill and a bad practice for models?
3. Say, user goes to an application page showing full animal info. Obviously, initially I have an `AnimalViewModel` with only `Id` and `Name` values (taken from `GetZoo`). As the page is navigated to, I call `GetAnimalStuffById` and get an `Animal` object with all the data. What should I do next? Replace the DataContext of my view with a new `AnimalViewModel` created from new `Animal` object (A), or just replace the values in it (B)?
4. If the answer is (A), how do I replace the DataContext in all the views?
5. If the answer is (B), what should cause that update? Should the VMs subscribe to some fancy manager's event about getting an `Animal` update? Or is there some other approach?
6. What is the purpose of `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the autogenerated classes? They are always returned fresh from the webservice in my case. Does Microsoft suggest to use them also as ViewModels in some scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few answers based on my own experience with MVVM (which may or may not be "best practice"..)

1. Absolutely! No need to do everything twice - see #5 and #6 (although there are people who disagree here).
2. Yes, unless you actually need the functionality of an `ObservableCollection` server-side, I would say it's overkill, and possibly confusing to others. Techincally, there's no overhead to the messages being sent across the wire, but I would go with something simpler, like an array.
3. Go with option B.
4. -
5. For example, you could have a single property in your `AnimalViewModel` to hold all the additional stuff: `public Animal AdditionalData { ...`. Now, whoever calls `GetAnimalStuffById` can just update the current ViewModel's AdditionalData with that `Animal` object.
6. I assume you already know that `INotifyPropertyChanged` is there to let the View know that some data has changed somewhere (if not, googling "inotifypropertychanged mvvm" should get you started). Now, connecting the dots from #1 and #5, your View can now bind to the animal's additional data by going *through the AdditionalData* property without having to recreate everything in the ViewModel: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=AdditionalData.HeightOrWhatever}" />`.

*Note: If your View isn't WPF or Silverlight, that last point won't make much sense..*

Answer (score 1):

And here's answers based on my experience (mainly to provide another point of view)

1. It's fine to autogenerate `Models` from an endpoint. But I would recommend POCO `Models` without any `INPC` cruft. Two reasons, a) it makes the `Models` simpler and easier to maintain and b) You won't be tempted to expose your `Models` directly to the `View`, or if you do they won't work properly.
2. Continuing on from #1, I would not use `ObservableCollection` in `Models`. Again to keep things simple and to avoid presenting `Models` directly to the `View`.
3. Option (B)
4. -
5. All the properties in the `ViewModel` should implement INPC. Then when you change them the binding will automatically update. You can either have all the `AdditionalData` values as properties of your `AnimalViewModel` which is flattening the data, or you can have an `AdditionalDataViewModel` object to hold the extra data. To map data from an `AdditionalData` object to `AdditionalDataViewModel` consider using a mapping tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).
6. I don't know why the autogenerator added `INPC` stuff into your models. What tool are you using? In any case as I've said I do not recommend having `INPC` in `Models`, or exposing `Models` to the `View`. Instead you should be mapping from `Models` to `ViewModels` and only exposing `ViewModels` to the `View`.

Comment: +1 for the mappers. Just out of interest: Why do you consider it such a no-no to expose your models?

Comment: @Sphinxxx In projects I've worked on when you expose the Model directly they become confused when you add View only properties, for example a Count, or a Visibility flag or SelectedItem property. Now your Model is polluted with View concepts. Whenever I've had Models with change logic in them they get complex (when x property here changes, update y property over on that object). In the end it's simpler to just have POCO Models and map values to a ViewModel.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Also, I maintain a very large MVVM application (100+ screens) so I have a lot of Models and ViewModels. I suspect for smaller apps complexity is less of an issue.

Comment: I see your point. I too wrap stuff that requires some logic into ViewModels, but for the rest of the "bare-bone" data, I usually just let the View edit the model instead of duplicating everything in the ViewModel (the projects that I maintain are mostly oriented towards raw data editing). Having said that though, I've never really looked at mapping tools.

Comment: @Sphinxxx Isn't letting the View edit the Model putting the business logic in the View?

Comment: No, just the business _information_, which will find its way to the Model anyway :) There will always be a ViewModel in-between which handles selection and other things that don't need to be stored, but for the basic stuff I usually expose the Model through a public property on the ViewModel. Of course, it's not without its flaws; in some cases the ViewModel may have to listen to the Model's PropertyChanged event to arrange some less-basic stuff, but there's no business logic in the Model (if by 'business logic' you mean code that actually does something useful). Anyways, that's how i do it...